# trouble with do while loop.. want to have while ==yes.option OR until index<MAX but it keeps looping

Tags: java, do-while

The below code just keeps looping even if the user selects the "no" option.

```
do{             
    addStudent();
    student.calcTuition(numCredits, fee);
    printStudent(); 
} while(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Another Student?") != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION
        || studentNum < 20);
```

I want to have this loop end if the user either doesn't have another student to enter or if the student count is above 20 so is my `studnetNum<20` syntax wrong? Because if I delete that, it obviously ends the loop after the user clicks no, but how do I have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is studentNum ? If it's the number of student updated by addStudent, then you need:

```
&& studentNum<20
```

You stay in the loop when both are true so you need a and, not a or.

Comment: Thanks! I always get this mixed up.